# Do while loops automatically suppress output from code enclosed by the while loop?

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I finished my assignment and it runs the way the descriptions in the prompts say it should.

This is more of a question of sheer curiosity.

Sometimes to find out where my code might not be working I'll remove the ';' at the end of statements in the script and let it output as much as it can before it hits the error. For small scripts I'm finding this useful. I haven't learned about using proper debugging features just yet.

Anyway, I have some code for an assignment

```
function endValue = tradeStock(initInvest, price, buy, sell)

% given an initial investment, vector of price fluctuations (price), vector
% of lows (buy), and a vector of peaks (sell), this function will return
% the final value of said initial investment. Assumed in the process is a
% per transaction cost of $12.95

% vectorization not possible, use loops

format bank

tcost = 12.95;
purse = initInvest;
endValue = 0;

if max(size(buy))~=max(size(sell))
    disp('Buy and sell vectors must be the same size')
    return
end

for i = 1:max(size(buy))
    stock = floor(purse/price(buy(i)));
    purch = stock*price(buy(i)) + tcost;
    while purse < purch
        stock = stock - 1;
        purch = stock*price(buy(i)) + tcost;
    end
    if purch <= 0   
        disp('You have run out of money before the market closed')
        endValue = initInvest;
        return
    end
    purse = purse - purch; % paid for stock
    purse = purse + stock*price(sell(i)) - tcost; % sell stock
end
endValue = purse;
```

If you start out with an initial Investment that is too small, the code should straight away enter the while loop, and then wind up in the following if then statement returning you from the function and giving you back your initial Investment. And this indeed happens if you enter in an initInvest that is too small.

However, if I remove the ';' from the code enclosed by the while loop, and run it with an initInvest value that is too small, no extra values are output from within the while loop upon execution.....

Do while loops just automatically suppress output from any enclosed code?

Comment: No. Use [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182) to see if it's actually entering the loop.

Comment: No. Most likely your code is not working the way you think it is, and not entering the while loop.

Comment: No, statements lacking a line-ending `;` within a `while`-loop will echo to the command window *if the code is reached*.  Likely, the `purch` variable is always larger than `purse` (and therefore `initInvest`) such that `purse < purch` is always false and the code is never reached.

Comment: YEP. I don't even need that while loop. It will never go into it, as the stock calc is floored anyway, and will default to zero on it's own if the purse isn't large enough.